# How do I use qqplot with r -f

Tags: r

I have this little script

```
library(ggplot2)

print(qplot(1:10, 1:10))

readLines("stdin", n = 1)
```

that I am trying to run with

```
r -f littleScript.R
```

Unfortunately, the expected plot is not displayed. In fact, nothing is displayed at all. I understand that I should use `print()` on `qplot()`'s output, yet, it doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running from a script, R doesn't invoke graphics by default.

You can add the command x11() to enable it:

```
library(ggplot2)
x11()
print(qplot(1:10, 1:10))

readLines("stdin", n = 1)
```

Alternatively you could save the plot by adding a call to jpeg/pdf etc etc:

```
library(ggplot2)
jpeg("myfilepath.jpg")
print(qplot(1:10, 1:10))
dev.off()
readLines("stdin", n = 1)
```